# Why does tiny-carousel work in all browsers but doesnt display anything in IE11?

Tags: javascript, tiny-carousel

Implemented a component using tiny-carousel which is built in jquery , it is working in all browsers except IE11. Any suggestions on how to fix or how to debug the issue or some hacks.

Comment: At first, open the DevTools in IE, and read the error messages ...

Comment: [The browser support](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider#browser-support) for Tiny Carousel lists `IE8+` so it's not a problem with the library. Must be a problem in your code. We cannot accurately guess what that would be.

Comment: @VLAZ the code works fine on all the browsers but for the IE11 It is only displaying the buttons

Comment: Again, the library supports IE8+. So it's not a problem there. We do not have the information to tell you how to fix what's wrong but it should be some of your code. You're most likely using a feature that is not supported in IE11 like arrow functions.

Comment: this is a AEM based project so in the bin link below I have added the code specific to this carousel component  https://jsbin.com/kamuqek/edit?html,css,js